# Не работает проверка PascalABCNET

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Я сделал выборочный калькулятор, т.е. в котором можно выбрать знак вычисления и числа, и для того чтоб не выдавало ошибку при вводе знака, я решил сделать проверку, которая срабатывает если `sign <> 'знак'`, за место 'знак' у меня +,- и т.д, но проверка срабатывает каждый раз даже если знак введен верно. В чем проблема?
Код:

```
program test;
label restart;
var
  a,b,signnum,rest:integer;
  sign:string;
begin
restart: rest := 0;
while rest <> 1 do
begin
a := 0;
b:=0;
sign:='';
writeln('Введите знак(/,*,+,-):');
readln(sign);
if (sign <> '-') or (sign <> '+') or (sign <> '/') or (sign <> '*') then
begin
  writeln('Вы используете несуществующий символ для вычисления!');
  goto restart;
end
else
continue;
writeln('Введите первое число: ');
readln(a);
writeln('Введите второе число: ');
readln(b);
if sign = '+' then
begin
writeln(a+b);
end;
if sign = '-' then
begin
writeln(a-b);
end;
if sign = '/' then
begin
writeln(a/b);
end;
if sign = '*' then
begin
writeln(a*b);
end;
end;
end.
```

Comment: Прочитайте в книжке или в хелпе, что делает continue, и опять же выкиньте goto

Comment: @MBo Как тогда делать перезапуск кода без `goto`? Мне нужно чтоб после ввода неправильного знака перезапускало код.

Comment: Cледуюший оборот while приведёт к новому вводу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо в условие and, а не or, очевидно одно из условий всегда сработает